# Does it makes any difference from module caching perspective how it is required?

Tags: node.js, module

Im trying to understand module caching. I've read lots of materials but it's still fuzzy because I can't find a good article that goes to full details and there are some contrary opinions going around the web.

```
const modules = {
  first: require('./modules/first.js'),
  second: require('./modules/second.js')
};

// vs

const first = require('./modules/first.js');
const second = require('./modules/second.js');
```

Does these two have any difference when it comes to caching (both are exported same way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it makes any difference from module caching perspective how it is required?

No, there is no difference in how the two modules are loaded in either of your scenarios.  Both are `require()`ed in when this parent module is first run so there is no difference in timing and the module being loaded would not know the difference.

> Does these two have any difference when it comes to caching (both are exported same way)?

No difference for caching.  Both modules will be cached in both scenarios.

There is a difference in the `const` declaration.  In your first one, `modules.first` and `modules.second` can still be assigned.  Only the `modules` variable itself is actually `const`.  So, you can't do `modules = {some other object}`, but you can reassign the individual `const.first` and `const.second` properties of that object.

In your second code example, both `first` and `second` are `const` and cannot be re-assigned.